# Need command line to start web browser using adb

Tags: android, adb

How can I start a browser with the `adb shell` command and make it open a certain web page?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, do you mean start a browser intent?

Comment: any app from CLI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools

Answer (score 274):

Running this command will start a web browser in android:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: I am trying to use this to load pre saved pages(on sdcard), but it gives error.

Comment: This was opening a new tab each time I fired it, resulting in a great mess of opened tabs after a while.

Comment: actually you need to remove "./" before executing that command.

Answer (score 61):

If your url's are symbol heavy you should also quote aggressively

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d 'http://stackoverflow.com/?uid=isme\&debug=true'
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to start Chrome specifically

```
adb shell am start \
-n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main \
-a android.intent.action.VIEW -d 'file:///sdcard/lazer.html'
```

Also give Chrome access to sdcard via

```
adb shell pm grant com.android.chrome android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Swap com.android.chrome with com.chrome.canary if you are using Chrome canary version.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to start silk on my kindle via adb, without adding a new url. I came up with this:

```
adb shell am start -n com.amazon.cloud9/.browsing.BrowserActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the default web browser with keyevents too (it's possible to write KEYCODE_EXPLORER instead of 64)

```
adb shell input keyevent 64
```

Enter an url submit: (66 -> KEYCODE_ENTER)

```
adb shell input text "stackoverflow.com" && adb shell input keyevent 66
```

Answer (score 0):

I add `--user 0` after start and work in jackpal emulator like this:

`adb shell am start --user 0 -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.stackoverflow.com`