# Android's browser do not call Application And auto search or notice invalid address

Tags: android, browser

I have one problem hope you help

I wanted to call down a application from web browser (on Android) by accessing the address with the schema of the app (the app that I also declare schema).
eg myschema://site/data1/data2
However, not all browsers are successful. the browser fails, it considered uri string call application are the wrong address (and can auto search)

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the issue you're having.

What I've found is you can't test [Deeplink schema](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) with Google's Chrome browser unless you create a specific webpage to test the links. Anything that isn't a "valid" URL is passed to Google as a search. So if you want to use Chrome, create a small HTML page with the links you want to test and when you click on the links, a working deeplink URL will open the application.

What I do when I don't want to go to that much effort is I download the [Firefox browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&hl=en) and paste the links into the URL bar there. That'll open the associated applications directly.

The third option is to use the ADB command line interface, see this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3512723/2353588).